# How to speed up a video on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, video, ffmpeg

In Ubuntu I have a 20 minute avi video file with audio, which I want to speed up 10fold. I have tried `kdenlive` and `openshot`, but they only speed up the video and not the audio. Using ffmpeg directly also does not work (spee up of audio only up to a factor of 10). I also tried to install `slowmovideo`, which seems to be offline or so.

So is there any other useful commandline/GUI tool around to speed up a video by a factor of 10, including audio (with high-piched audio result, that is OK)?

Comment: ffmpeg will speed up audio 10 fold, video as well.

Comment: Let me add something to the question: it would be great if we could speed-up a video the way YouTube and VLC do - without altering the audio pitch (although speeding up the audio). I use an old-fashioned portable MP3-player to listen to audio books and I speed the MP3s up using Audacity before writing them to the player. I also use an old-fashioned (not "smart") TV to watch videos from an USB flash drive and I'd like to pre-speed-up the video files the same way.